# Tensorflow GPU Memory Allocation Affects Model Accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, gpu

I have a neural net in Keras 2.2.2, Tensorflow 1.10.0, Ubuntu 18, GTX1080Ti. I trained the model using a) all of the GPU memory and b) approximately half (0.47) of the memory. I get dramatically different results between these cases. Full memory - good result. Half memory - bad. I have repeated these tests and the results are consistent. The model code is too elaborate to show here but I am wondering if this is a known general effect. I set the memory allocation with this code:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.47
session = tf.Session(config=config)
K.set_session(session)
```

Batch size is calculated in the code at runtime and is not affected by GPU memory allocation.

Comment: Can you share more details regarding the process, like whether you are using multiple gpus, training using fit or fit_generator, no of batches you have for training?

Comment: @kvish I use a single GPU. Training is via keras model.fit. I train for 100 epochs.

Comment: @kvish: Clarification: I train for a maximum of  100 epochs. I use keras early stopping callbacks so the actual training epochs are typically < 100.

Comment: this is just a wild guess. Can you check your results what happens when you set shuffle=False in your model.fit instead of the default True?

Comment: @kvish. I finally ran the test comparing shuffle True/False. No significant difference. Thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Comment: thank you for following up on that! Have you been able to resolve this problem?